# rails 3 find() between now and midnight

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have an event model which has start_at of type datetime. How can I search to find if there is an Event left for today, so start_at between now and midnight.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Rails 3, you can do this now:

> **Range Conditions**
>
> If you’re looking for a range inside
>   of a table (for example, users created
>   in a certain timeframe) you can use
>   the conditions option coupled with the
>   IN SQL statement for this. If you had
>   two dates coming in from a controller
>   you could do something like this to
>   look for a range:

```
Client.where(:created_at => (params[:start_date].to_date)..(params[:end_date].to_date))
```

So in your case it would be:

```
Event.where(:start_at => (Time.zone.now)..(Time.zone.now.end_of_day))
```

Just tested and it also works without parentheses around `Time.zone.now` and `Time.zone.now.end_of_day`.

(From [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html))

Comment: I have an event with start_date as 2011-05-14 08:06:00 -0500 but `Event.where(:start_at => '2011-05-14 08:00:00 -0500'..'2011-05-14 08:10:00 -0500')` returns me an empty array.

Comment: Maybe it works if you use a date object instead of a string: `Event.where(:start_at => '2011-05-14 08:00:00'.to_date..'2011-05-14 08:10:00'.to_date)`. If this doesn't help, please post the generated SQL.

Answer (score 3):

```
Event.where('start_at >= ? and start_at <= ?', Time.zone.now, Time.zone.now.end_of_day)
```

You will have to deal with user time zones if you want this to be completely accurate for multiple users.

Answer (score 0):

```
Event.where("start_at BETWEEN ? AND ?", Time.zone.now, Time.zone.now.end_of_day)
```